# How to work with two pipes while sending data between child and parent process?

Tags: c, kernel, pipe, fork, system-calls

I am learning about system calls, fork and pipe. I am creating a C program in which the parent process sends a character array to the child process and child process capitalizes the first 4 characters of the array and sends it back. The array is sent properly from parent to child, child makes the conversion and even writes to the second pipe properly, but parent process is not able to read the new array from the pipe 2.

I've tried closing the unnecessary descriptors as well, but that didn't work. I read somewhere that parent process might be finishing before there is something to read from the pipe, for which I tried wait function(but I might have done this wrong. I am not sure.)

I tried checking the size of values sent and received by the processes,

Parent writes (8)

Child reads (8)

Child writes (8)

Parent reads (1)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];
    char str[8], str1[8];
    pid_t pid;

    if(pipe(pipe1) < 0){
        perror("Pipe 1 not created\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pipe(pipe2) < 0){
        perror("Pipe 2 not created\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0){
        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);
        printf("\nChild Process");
        ssize_t rd_stat_child = read(pipe1[0], str, 8*sizeof(char));
        if(rd_stat_child > 0){
            printf("rc%zd\n", rd_stat_child);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                str[i] = ((char)(((int)str[i])-32));
            }

            printf("\nFinal str in child: %s\n", str);
            ssize_t wr_stat_child = write(pipe2[1], str, 8*sizeof(char));
            printf("wc%zd\n", wr_stat_child);
            if(wr_stat_child != sizeof(str)){
                perror("Sending to parent failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }else{
            perror("Child failed to read");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }else if (pid > 0){
        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(pipe2[1]);
        printf("\nParent Process");
        printf("\nEnter a 8 character string: ");
        scanf("%s", str);
        if(sizeof(str)/(8*sizeof(char)) != 1){
            perror("Size of string greater than 8\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else{
            ssize_t wr_stat_parent = write(pipe1[1], str, 8*sizeof(char));
            printf("wp%zd\n", wr_stat_parent);
            if(wr_stat_parent != sizeof(str)){
                perror("Parent failed writing.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            ssize_t rd_stat_parent = read(pipe2[0], str, 8*sizeof(char));
            close(pipe2[0]);
            if(rd_stat_parent <= sizeof(str)){
                printf("rp%zd\n", rd_stat_parent);
                printf("\nParent Recieved\n %s", str);
            }else{
                perror("Parent error while reading\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Expected Output

Parent Process
(input) >> lkybzqgv

Child Process
(process) >> LKYBzqgv

Parent Process
(output) >> LKYBzqgv

#### Actual Output

Parent Process
(input) >> lkybzqgv

Child Process
(process) >> LKYBzqgv

Parent Process
(output) >> kybzqgv

Comment: Just because you write N bytes to one end of a pipe or stream socket in one go doesn't mean you'll read N bytes in one go on the other end.

Comment: But why does it work in case of a Child process but in the case of Parent process? And then how can I do this?

Comment: Undefined behavior for out-of-bounds write.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Not the issue, but `sizeof(str)` tells you about the buffer size, not the content length, and anyway you need 9 characters to store a zero terminated 8 letter string.  `strlen(str)/(8*sizeof(char))` is integer maths and won't do what you think it will!

Answer (score 1):

Your string-handling is broken. You need an array of length 9 to hold a string of length 8. (Remember that strings in c are zero-terminated). ***DO NOT WRITE `scanf("%s", str);` TO READ STRINGS !!*** That is just as bad as using `gets()`. It allows you to overflow the buffer (Which actually happens in your case). Read strings like this:

```
scanf("%8s", str);
```

This will read at most 8 (non-whitespace) characters and store them together with the zero-termination in str. (remember again that str must be large enough for 8 charecters + 1 termination character)

Then to check the length of a string, use `strlen()`, do not use `sizeof()`. `sizeof` may only tell the size of the array holding the string, or the pointer pointing to the string. Remember that the array holding the string must be at least 1 character larger than the string, but is allowed to be larger than that. And the size of the array is fixed at creation. It doesn't change size depending on what you put in it.

Oh, and by the way. You don't send/receive the termination character, so you have to set it yourself manually after you have called read():

```
read(pipe1[0], str, 8);
str[8] = 0;
```

There may be other problems with your code, but unless you fix the string-issues, you have undefined behavior, and everything else doesn't really matter.